# In Laravel how do i create a query string?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

This will be obvious to someone else

I have a route that works and goes to the correct controller

```
Route::get('v1/holidays/{country}/{year}/{month}/{official?}',
'retrieveHolidayController@test'
```

so if i go to 
    http://example.com/v1/holidays/US/2014/03/01

it will go where I want to go

however I want the link to look like

http://example.com/v1/holidays?country=US&year=2014&month=03&official=01

How can I do this please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You redefine your route to

```
Route::get('v1/holidays', 'retrieveHolidayController@test');
```

Then in your controller you can get the param values with $request

```
public function test(Request $request)
{
    if ( $request->has('country') && $request->country != '') {
        $country = $request->country;
    }

    if ( $request->has('year') && $request->year != '') {
        $year = $request->year;
    }

    .... // and the others. Then you can query like this

    $holidays = Holiday::when($country, function($query) use ($country) {
        return $query->where('country', $country);
    })
    ->when($year, function($query) use ($year) {
        return $query->where('year', $year);
    })
    ->get();

    //Using 'when' only executes the closure if the variable exists
}
```

Now, you can use your URL just the way you wanted:
 http://example.com/v1/holidays?country=US&year=2014&month=03&official=01

Answer (score 0):

Make `country,year and month`also optional:-

```
Route::get('v1/holidays/{country?}/{year?}/{month?}/{official?}', 'retrieveHolidayController@test')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('v1/holidays', 'retrieveHolidayController@test');

Route::get('v1/holidays/{country}/{year}/{month}/{official?}', function($country){
    return redirect()->to(action('retrieveHolidayController@test', ["country"=>$country,......]));
});
```

access to `http://example.com/v1/holidays/US/2014/03/01`

redirect to `http://example.com/v1/holidays?country=US&year=2014&month=03&offical=01`

if official param is null redirect param `offical=` param is nullable

not feel good
so

```
isset($official){
     $paramArry["official"] = $official;
}
```